# Testing if a player is standing on certain tiles of an integer array

Tags: arrays, 2d, lwjgl, tile

I am trying to make a game in which a player will only fall if they aren't standing on specific tiles. My map is generated using an integer array that corresponds with various tile types. I was wondering if there is any way to test if the tile below the player is a certain tile, besides making an if else statement for every tile. I have given an example of one of the maps and how I am testing if a player is standing on it.

```
int[][] map3 = {                                                     //grid3
                { 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 0, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6 },
                { 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6 },
                { 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 0, 6, 7, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6 },
                { 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6 },
                { 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 0, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6 },
                { 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 0, 6, 0 },
                { 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 6, 6, 6, 6 },
                { 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 5, 1, 1, 1 },
                { 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9 },
                { 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9 }, };

if (grid3.getTile( (int) playerX, (int) playerY) != grid3.map[7][4]) {
                player.setY((float) ((float) player.getY() - 0.7));
            }
```

I would repeat this process for every ground tile.

Answer (score 0):

You should just be able to use nested for loops to iterate over your arrays.
It would look something like this.

```
for(int c = 0; c < grid3.map.length; c++){

    for(int x = 0; x < grid3.map[c].length){

        if (grid3.getTile( (int) playerX, (int) playerY) != grid3.map[c][x])
            player.setY((float) ((float) player.getY() - 0.7));

    }
}
```